# styling background of selected option

Tags: html, css, background, html-select

I have this code here on jsfiddle for a select box:
https://jsfiddle.net/v7tqumpe/1/

I want to be able to change the background color of a selected option. It defaults to blue, but I want to change this as well as the color of the text. After some searching, I found that the css for a selected option is option:checked. So, I tried this:

```
.body > select > option:checked { 
    background: black;
    color: red;
}
```

But, this doesn't seem to do anything, and the background stays as blue while the color of the text stays as white. How can I change these colors?

In addition, I want to change the background/color for when a selected option is out of focus (right now, it defaults to a gray background which is pretty ugly imo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Complete code: [Change background of selected
>   option](https://codepen.io/Adeel91/pen/YVpxXe)

Actually, you cannot style all CSS properties on `:checked` option elements. `color` , `background-color` doesn't work directly so you have to use `background` instead.

HTML:

```
<div class="body">
    <select size="7" class="form-control" id="subjects">
        <option>one</option>
        <option>two</option>
        <option>three</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.body > select option:checked { 
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, black 0%, black 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(0deg, black 0%, black 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(0deg, black 0%, black 100%);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since no one seems to have an answer, I'll say what worked for me, a slight hack.
It turns out the operating system sets the background color of a select option, so the background color is not able to be changed with css.
However, the box-shadow property works instead like this:

```
.body > select > option:checked { 
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 100px #00B2F3 inset;
}
```

It allows you to set the color and say inset, meaning only the current option selected.

Now, its working:
https://jsfiddle.net/v7tqumpe/5/

The text color is not able to be changed though, so it is still white.

Here is the full code:

```css
.body > select > option { 
  padding-top: 1px;
  cursor: default;
 }
 .body > select > option:checked { 
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 100px #00B2F3 inset;
 }
 .body > select { 
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(100% - 10px);
  color: #00B2F3;
  border: 1px solid #00B2F3;
  padding: 0px 0px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="body">

  <select size="7" class="form-control" id="subjects">
    <option>one</option>
                <option>two</option>
                <option>three</option>
  </select>

</div>
```